# How to deal with JSON results in JQuery using $.Ajax

Tags: jquery

I have a FORM with three elements; a text field, and two select dropdown elements:

```
<input type="text" name="UserCode" id="UserCode">
<select name="OrderCode" id="OrderCode"></select>
<select name="RegionCode" id="RegionCode"></select>
```

When the text in the `UserCode` field is changed, I am tying to use JQuery to fire off a request to get some data about that User. The data is returned in JSON format. Here is what the JSON data looks like (copied from Firebug console):

```
{
"COLUMNS":["ORDERTITLE","ORDERCODE"],
"DATA":[
        ["Marketing","00000381"],["Fashion and Textile Buying Management","00006058"]
       ]
}
```

The JQuery code that allows the above to happen is this (so far):

```
$(function() {
    $('#UserCode').blur(function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/_assets/cfc/orders/order-dbqueries.cfc',
            data: {method:'account_customer_Orders', UserCode:$(this).val()},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result){
            //NO IDEA WHAT TO DO HERE TO GET THE JSON DATA INTO THE #ORDERCODE SELECT FORM ELEMENT
            } 
        });
});
});
```

I have some questions:

1. How do I get the JSON data returned to populate the #OrderCode
   select element with attributes like such: `<option
   value="OrderCode"> OrderTitle </option>`
2. If question 1 can be resolved successfully, then the next step is that my URL needs to return more than one result set in order to populate the other  element with ID #RegionCode. How can the JQuery code handle two JSON returns if that's even possible?

Comment: It looks like you are simply returning the results of a query as JSON, this might not be the best way to handle it given the way the data gets formatted. I would loop over the query, create a structure for each row in query with keys being `OrderTitle` and `OrderCode` and append those to an array - so you have an array of structures that gets returned. Then you simply loop over that array and append `option`s to the `select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your success function put:

```
$.map(result.DATA, function(val, i) {
    $("select[name='OrderCode']").append($("<option></option>").val(val[1]).text(val[0]));
});
```

Now you can fill second select #RegionCode with same $.map function but different data.

Comment: Tried the code and what happens is that in the <select name="OrderCode"> element it just displays the column name "OrderTitle"

Comment: I edited my answer. This code fill your first select with data from result.DATA. If you want fill second select you need select from database records for #RegionCode (append it to current json data) and fill second select with $.map function.

Comment: Thank you, it works... but I have no clue how its doing what its doing. It is putting in "Marketing" into the display value for the Select element which is great. How would I then display it as "OrderTitle (OrderCode)" so e.g. "Marketing (00000381)"

Comment: You need modify text() function.     $("select[name='OrderCode']").append($("<option></option>").val(val[1]).text(val[0]+" ("+val[1]+")"));

Answer (score 0):

I looked at Łukasz's solution and then through trial and error I came up with this myself which also works:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#UserCode').blur(function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/_assets/cfc/orders/order-dbqueries.cfc',
        data: {method:'account_customer_Orders', UserCode:$(this).val()},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            $.each(result.DATA, function(index, value)
            {
            $("#OrderCode").append(
"<option value="+value[1]+">"+value[0]+" ("+value[1]+")"+"</option>");
    });             
    }
    });
    });
    });
```

@Łukasz do you mind explaining why and what the text() function did in your solution and you did it differently to me? Is it because my next step will be trying to work out how to deal with two JSON results?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Your solution is vulnerable to XSS attacks. If user can add data (in another part of your page) which you are append to select and this user put js code than this code will be executed. When you put value and text to option with val() and text() than javascript wont execute (just will be displayed on a page).